# Is there a way to create a Tumblr page that doesn't require logging in?

Tags: tumblr

I just started a Tumblr page and shared the link with people, but they told me they didn't enter the site because they were prompted to login and didn't want to bother creating an account.

I looked around in the settings and I couldn't find any way to disable this requirement and just make the Tumblr page available to anyone on the internet.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the address I was trying to access, was the editing page and not the public URL.

That is, I was trying to access

```
https://www.tumblr.com/blog/mynewblog
```

instead of

```
http://mynewblog.tumblr.com/
```